# Adding JComponent with JLabel to another JPanel causes IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, user-interface

I was wondering how to label my buttons, sliders, etc. properly, so I came up with a solution that I found to be quiet good since I'm new to gui development.

This class below should allow me to label any JComponent and set the label position to North,East,South or West of the JComponent.

Unfortunately `new LabeledComponent<>("Depth", new JSlider(1, 10, 21), LabeledComponent.LabelPosition.North);` runs into an IllegalArgumentException but why?

Is there something wrong with the Generics ?

```
    public class LabeledComponent<E extends JComponent> extends JPanel {

    public enum LabelPosition {
        North,
        South,
        East,
        West
    }

    public LabeledComponent(String label, E component, LabelPosition position) {
        JLabel label1 = new JLabel(label);
        switch (position) {
            case North -> {
                setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
                add(label1);
                add(component);
            }
            case South -> {
                setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
                add(component);
                add(label1);
            }
            case East -> {
                setLayout(new FlowLayout());
                add(component);
                add(label1);
            }
            case West -> {
                setLayout(new FlowLayout());
                add(label1);
                add(component);
            }
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: Can you post the code where you use this class cause it seems fine?

Comment: Post an [mre] demonstrating the problem. We should be able to copy/paste/compile/test to see the problem. In addition to the above we need to see how you create the frame and add the LabeledComponent to the frame. Code should be in a single source file.

Comment: *IllegalArgumentException* - and what does the full message say?

Answer (score 0):

new JSlider(1, 10, 21); causes IllegalArgumentException because JSlider Constructor takes minvalue, maxvalue and value. 21 is out of bounds.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).